# Change the title of strut action showing in browser

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, browser, struts

I'm trying to open a PDF file in browser through struts action. But when I open the window it is showing me the name of the action instead of the title what I am trying to set for that window. How should I set the title for the window?

[image]

As shown in the image, viewPdfDocument.do appears in the window and even in the title of the window. I want to change it.

Comment: I think you can configure your titles in your tiles.xml file.

Comment: How can I do that? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

i think there should be .properties file somewhere in your project, you can change a .title value within this file

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how should I go further with it?